# How to get only log.i values from logcat of Application?

Tags: android, logcat

I want to save logcat values, specifically LOG.I, of my application in sdcard.
I have used following code to get all log values but unable to filter it to get only specific log.i values. Please suggest how to do it?

```
 try {
       File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gphoto4.html"); 
            filename.createNewFile(); 
            String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: ok i vill improve. If u know how to get log values. Plz tell.

Comment: @imran khan : Thanks for replying

Comment: @android_pb : your problem get solved or not?

Comment: @android_pb : i my answer i'm using `commandLine.add( "tag:W");`  so try after changing it to `commandLine.add( "tag:I");`

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Just change your code,

```
String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
```

with

```
String cmd = "logcat -v time -r 100 -f <filename> [TAG]:I [MyApp]:D *:S";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

you don't have to create file by your self just execute the above command, to get the Your application's specific tag info.

Here

```
-v -> Sets the output format for log messages.
-r -> for specifying the size of file.
-f -> file to which you want to write the logs.
[TAG] -> Tag of your application's log.
[MyApp] -> Your application name.
```

Comment: I have used bellow codebut it shows blank html file *************try { File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gphoto4.html"); 
      filename.createNewFile(); 
      String cmd = "logcat [TAG]:I [MyApp]:D *:S"+filename.getAbsolutePath();
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Actually this works in my case, "logcat [TAG]:I [MyApp]:D *:S > /mnt/sdcard/log.out"

Answer (score 0):

May not be a direct answer, but I think this can be useful for you [Application Crash Report for Android](http://code.google.com/p/acra/),

I have used this in some of my projects it works like wonder.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but actually i want to save only LOG.I value in sd card.

Comment: in that case have you tried solution provided in another answer by @user370305